# How to update the AWS APIGateway settings for cloudwatch ARN?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I am trying to find a way to update the cloud watch Arn in AWS APIGateway using AWS CLI or API method if available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CloudWatch ARN can be set using the API Gateway by performing a PATCH on the cloudwatchRoleArn property of the Account resource. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/account/#cloudwatchRoleArn

Using the AWS CLI, the CloudWatch ARN can be set by calling update-account.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-account.html

Using the Java SDK, the CloudWatch ARN can be set by calling updateAccount.

Comment: Using the Java SDK, the CloudWatch ARN can be set by calling updateAccount.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html